# Convert org.springframework.core.io.Resource to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile without storing the file on disk

Tags: java, spring

I have method which returns the content as `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` and I need to pass the `Resource` to another method which accepts the `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile[]`
Can any one help me, how should i do it as i did not find any method or approach to do it to `MultipartFile` format. If any standard method or sample code would be there , will be of great help.

PS: I do not want to save the file on disk for this purpose

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Syed, welcome to SO. I understand what you're asking, but could you please elaborate on your use case? How will you be using the MultipartFile that using the Resource wouldn't be enough?

Comment: I have to consume an API which takes multipartfile as a parameter. So I need to convert the Resource object into multipartfile

Comment: Are you consuming a REST API? If so, you need a `File`, which you can just use the method `Resource#getFile()`. How are you connecting to it? RestTemplate, WebClient?

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcos. I was able to change the value from Multipartfile to Resource so I do not need the conversion now